Correlation function of a two-level quantum system coupled to a thermal bath
I am trying to quantify the temporal correlations of observables in an open quantum system, i.e. calculate a quantity of the type,
\begin{equation}
\langle n(t) n(t') \rangle - \langle n(t)\rangle \langle n(t') \rangle .
\end{equation}
To make things simple, I was considering a classical two level system initially. For the occupation of, say the lower level $n_1$, one may write down a rate equation in the following way:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t n_1 = -r_1 n_1 + r_2 n_2 - j_\uparrow(t) + j_\downarrow(t).
\end{equation}
The $j(t)$ are Langevin terms of Poisson type, i.e. their fluctuations coincide with the average rates of exchange between the two levels,
\begin{equation}
\langle j_\uparrow (t) j_\uparrow(t') \rangle = r_1 \langle n_1 \rangle \delta(t-t'),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\langle j_\downarrow (t) j_\downarrow(t') \rangle = r_2 \langle n_2 \rangle \delta(t-t').
\end{equation}
With this, it is straightforward to calculate $\langle n_1(t) n_1(t') \rangle$.
Here comes the issue: Now I tried to reproduce the rate equation in a two level quantum system that is coupled to a thermal bath. In my derivation, I started by considering a stochastic Schrödinger equation with Poisson noise. Using that, I derived a Langevin equation for the density matrix,
\begin{equation}
\partial_t \rho = \mathcal{D}\rho + j_\downarrow(t) \left(\frac{\sigma^- \rho \sigma^+}{\langle \sigma^+\sigma^-\rangle} - \rho\right) - j_\uparrow(t) \left(\frac{\sigma^+ \rho \sigma^-}{\langle \sigma^-\sigma^+\rangle} - \rho\right).
\end{equation}
Here I introduced the superoperator (called dissipator) \mathcal{D}\rho, this one gives the correct static exchange rates between the levels via projection. The operators $\sigma^+$ and $\sigma^-$ are ladder operators of the two level system. The $j(t)$ satisfy the same correlations as in the classical case. Here lies the problem though, projecting the Langevin equation on e.g. the first level gives
\begin{equation}
\partial_t n_1 = -r_1 n_1 + r_2 n_2 - j_\uparrow(t)n_1 + j_\downarrow(t)n_2.
\end{equation}
There are extra factors of $n_1$ and $n_2$! So something seems to be wrong.
I understand that I left out a lot of details, but still hope that maybe someone encountered a similar problem and might help me out. Thanks for reading!
